# script a dynamic code to insert values into variables and also variables are the column names

Tags: mysql

How do I write a dynamic script whereby the column name;

GST is a variable and I want it to be dynamically calculated based on the formula whenever there is data insert into the gross_sales column

```
SET @GST = gross_sales * 0.07, @gross_sales = 'gross_sales';

INSERT INTO sales(invoice_no, GST, gross_sales)
VALUES ('INV-1', @GST, 11.00),
       ('INV-2', @GST, 1.20),
       ('INV-3', @GST, 1.20);
```

I want the values of the GST column to be calculated automatically whenever data is being inputted into the gross_sales column. I have tried declaring the variables but it didn't work out.

Comment: In which programming language you want to create this dynamic script?

Comment: is it possible to write this in sql language?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? If your MySQL version >= 5.7, then you can look at Generated/Calculated Columns in MySQL. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: my MySQL version is 8.0; how do I create a calculated column?

Comment: Do you think triggers may help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger is what you are looking for.
You need to create a `before insert` trigger to calculate the value of gst.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `calc_gst`
 BEFORE INSERT
 ON `sales`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   set new.gst = new.gross_sales*0.07;
 END
delimiter ;
```

And you will be inserting values like this :

```
insert into sales values('inv-1',0,100);
```

Comment: @haroldquek You can select the answer if it helped you, so it will help other user those who come to this post.